# Increase the space between legend keys and align them in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to align my legend positions when those are customised and want to be at the bottom of the graph. In addition I want to increase the space between them. Here is a my gig-lot code:

```
p<-ggplot(aggregate(cbind(Tax_Burden,debt_GDP) ~ cou, data=df, mean, na.rm=TRUE), aes(x=log(debt_GDP), y=log(Tax_Burden))) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Tax_Burden, size=debt_GDP))+  
  labs(color = "Tax Burden\n[% Total\nRevenues]", size = "Public Debt [% GDP]")+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, linetype="dashed")+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = cou), size = 2)+
  ylab("Log of Tax Burden") +
  xlab("Log of Public Debt [% GDP]") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text =element_text(family="Times New Roman"),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.key   = element_blank(),
        legend.text  = element_text(size = 4),
        legend.title = element_text(size=6),
        legend.position=c(0.75, 0.15),
        legend.box = "horizontal", 
        legend.spacing.x = unit(-0.05, 'cm'),
        legend.margin = margin(-0.5,0,0,0, unit="cm"),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8))+
        guides(colour=guide_legend(nrow=2))+
        guides(size=guide_legend(nrow=2))
print(p)
```

and here is the picture:

[image]

As you see in the picture, legends are two close to each other, while are not very well aligned.

How I can improve this in ggplot?

Comment: I would simply remove those aesthetics as they don't add much information to that on the axes. (the axes might be more informative with `scale_x_log10` than log transforming the data)

Comment: Sorry, which aesthetics among all to drop ?

Comment: Colour and size